# Finding the Names of active threads inside a threadpool : ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

So I am running an executor service and I would like to know the Names or the threadIDs of all the currently active/idle threads.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)
```

I do not need to know the count, but the actual names/IDs of all the active threads in my executor service. I need to identify the threads in any manner because I plan on implementing my own ThreadFactory with an appropriate naming convention.

For example, if my active threads are T0,T1,T3, my threadfactory would name the next thread as T2. But I can't find a way to get information about the active Threads.
How can I do that?

PS : Any other methods would also be appreciated. For example, lets say I am fine with having threads with names from T0 to T50. I just want my current threadfactory to assign any name from T0 to T50 such that a thread with the same name is not currently active or idle.

Comment: Are you passing your threadFactory to the executorService? If yes, you could cache all the names that are given in your factory

Comment: Yes I am passing it. Could you please tell me how?

Comment: Well everytime a new `Thread` is created in your `ThreadFactory` you just cache that instance in a `Map<String, Thread>` where the key is the name of the `Thread`. That way you know what names are already gone and which are available. You'd have to clean up that cache regularly though

Comment: Thats what I was thinking. But the issue arrises when threads start getting killed. How do I know which threads were killed and what names to remove from my cache?

Comment: Okay are you suggesting I use Map.get(threadName).isAlive(). Would that work? and would that be thread-safe? I do not wish to synchronize any objects.

Comment: Not a clean way, but you can use reflection to get ThreadGroup.`threads `and `groups`

Comment: This seems like a lot of trouble to go to for no discernible gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so free to create you a sample, of something I would've done. I couldn't really test it though:

```
public class CachingThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory{
    // amount of active threads at max
    private static final int THREAD_POOL_MAX_SIZE = 8;

    // interval in milliseconds of the clean up task
    private static final int CLEAN_UP_INTERVAL = 2000;

    // the actual cache
    private final Thread[] cachedThreads = new Thread[THREAD_POOL_MAX_SIZE];

    // clean up task definition
    {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new CleanUpTask(), 0, CLEAN_UP_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Thread newThread(Runnable r){
        for(int i = 0; i < cachedThreads.length; i++){
            if(cachedThreads[i] == null){
                return cachedThreads[i] = new Thread(r, "T" + i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private final class CleanUpTask extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run(){
            synchronized(CachingThreadFactory.this){
                for(int i = 0; i < cachedThreads.length; i++){
                    final Thread thread = cachedThreads[i];
                    if(thread != null && !thread.isAlive()){
                        cachedThreads[i] = null; // unset
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This Factory caches every Thread it creates in an array. Then it runs a cleanUpTask asynchronly which checks if the threads in the array (if any) are still alive. If not they are removed.

The `newThread` method iterates through the cache, to find an index which is not yet taken, and then uses that index to create the name of that `Thread`. If no place is free it just returns `null`.

This class is probably thread safe. But I haven't really tested it. The `synchronized`-statements should prevent the interference between the cleanUp-Task and the newThread method. But any other action may disturb the whole thing.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you so much. I shall test it. :)

Comment: @KeyurJain you're welcome. But please *do* test it through. I am really not 100% sure if it behaves like it should

Answer (score 0):

call instead

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool(ThreadFactory threadFactory)
```

and pass your implementation of ThreadFactory. There you can manage thread names at thread creation time.

Answer (score -1):

Connect to your running program via jconsole or jvisual vm. It will give you all the running threads and their names.

Comment: OP probably wants to find out the names programmaticaly